# Convert Exponential number to string

Tags: c#

I am using the below code to convert exponential number to string. It's working partially.
Please help me to do this.

This is my Exponential number is 4.00658E+16 //In text format '40065812120130567'

The below code convert this number to 40065812120130600. Some times it didn't convert the last two digits. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
 decimal device;
 string dvc_id = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][4]);//dt.Rows[i][4]

 decimal.TryParse(dvc_id, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out device);
 dvc_id = device.ToString();
```

Comment: Could you please update sample with value of `dvc_id`? `decimal.TryParse("40065812120130567", out device);` produces exactly the result you say it does not.

Comment: did you use the exponential number?

Comment: The exponential number isn't the same number. It drops off every digit past the first 8.

Comment: What data type is dt.Rows[i][4]?

Comment: The exponential number

Answer (score 1):

The number `4.00658121201306E+16`, which you say you are using, is NOT the same as `40065812120130567`. The last two digits are dropped because the exponential form does not have those digits as part of the number.

The last two digits aren't stored at all in that number. All exponential notation does is tell where the decimal point should be, essentially. What you see is what you get in terms of the precision of the value, and you're not giving the program any digits after the six. Hence, it won't give you any digits after the six.

Comment: I just upload the number from csv. It having a record '40065812120130567'. Now i want to convert this number to string.

Comment: If it is ever in exponential form, you're losing those digits. `Decimal` can handle that large of a number, so nothing in the code you've posted is bad. Whatever is going wrong must be earlier in the process, and isn't included in your question. However, if, as you said, "I am using the below exponential 4.00658121201306E+16" at any point in your code, you are losing those digits. Look at your usage of exponential notation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code

```
var num = Decimal.Parse("4.00658E+16", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggested use BigInteger class:

```
var number = BigInteger.Parse("400658121201306000000000000");
```

Comment: Are you including the reference for System.Numerics?

Comment: It returns the error value could not be paresd.I am using the below exponential 4.00658121201306E+16